# Question about some of the science in "Passengers"

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, observers

In the movie "Passengers", there is a spaceship that is moving at half of the speed of light towards a destination planet orbiting another star, and the story takes place about 30 years after the launch of the spacecraft.   I want to keep this question as spoiler free as possible here, but that much information is necessary for the context of my question.

It occurs to me, however, that this 30 years is probably going to be as measured by the clocks on the ship, and not as measured by the clocks back on earth, since the ship is moving so fast.   The time dilation is pretty easy to calculate for a constant speed, but if we assume that the ship had actually been accelerating for all of that time with a constant amount of thrust, then the rate at which clocks tick on board the ship would be constantly changing.   So if it was 30 years as measured by the ship's clock since they left earth, how much time would have actually gone by on earth in the 30 years it had been since launch?   From there, I could measure how many Newtons of force per metric ton would be required to accelerate it to that speed.  However, because the ship is approaching relativistic speeds, and the effective mass of the ship must have also increased, would it appear from the perspective of the systems on board the ship that the thrust was decreasing, and was no longer as much as it once was at launch, even though its thrusters were going at a constant rate?

Comment: To do this, you will have to specify some acceleration rate, so that you have the velocity as a function of time. Then just integrate $dt/\sqrt{1 - v(t)^2/c^2}$

Comment: I am thinking, however, that acceleration would not be constant, because as the spaceship gets closer to the speed of light, its mass would increase, and the effective acceleration that could be achieved with the same amount of work would drop.  If it did not, you could reach the speed of light with only a finite amount of work.

Comment: You are right. If it was constant at a g it would take about a year to get to the speed of light. V= gt